# How to avoid duplicated SELECT phrases in SQL (MariaDB)

Tags: sql, duplicates, mariadb

I am working with a small MariaDB database. To extract time intervals per user, I use the following query:

```
SELECT
  SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,Activity.startTime,Activity.endTime)) AS seconds,
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,Activity.startTime,Activity.endTime))),'%Hh %im %ss') AS formattedTime,
  TSUser.name
FROM Activity
INNER JOIN User ON User.id = Activity.userID
GROUP BY User.id
ORDER BY seconds DESC;
```

I have to select the time as plain seconds (`... AS seconds`) to be able to order the results by it, as can be seen in my query.

However, I also want MariaDB to format the time interval, for that I use the `TIME_FORMAT` function. The problem is, I have to duplicate the whole `SUM(...)` phrase inside the `TIME_FORMAT` call again. This doesn't seem very elegant. Will MariaDB recognize the duplication and calculate the `SUM` only once? Also, is there a way to get the same result without duplicating the `SUM`?

I figured this should be possible with a nested query construct like so:

```
SELECT
  innerQuery.name,
  innerQuery.seconds,
  TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(innerQuery.seconds), '%Hh %im')
FROM (
  //Do the sum here, once.
) AS innerQuery
ORDER BY innerQuery.seconds DESC;
```

Is this the best way to do it / "ok" to do?

Note: I don't need the raw seconds in the result, only the formatted time is needed.

I'd appreciate help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Alas.  There isn't a really good solution.  When you use a subquery, then MariaDb materializes the subquery (as does MySQL).  Your query is rather complex, so there is a lot of I/O happening anyway, so the additional materialization may not be important.

Repeating the expression is really more an issue of aesthetics than performance.  The expression will be re-executed multiple times.  But, the real expense of doing aggregations is the file sort for the `group by` (or whatever method is used).  Doing the `sum()` twice is not a big deal (unless you are calling a really expensive function as well as the aggregation function).

Other database engines do not automatically materialize subqueries, so using a subquery in other databases is usually the recommended approach.  In MariaDB/MySQL, I would guess that repeating the expression is more efficient, although you can try both on your data and report back.

Answer (score 1):

In *this* case, you don't need the raw values.  The formatted value will work correctly in the `ORDER BY`.

Your subquery idea is likely to be slower because of all the overhead in having two queries.

This is a Rule of Thumb:  It takes far more effort for MySQL to fetch a row than to evaluate expressions in the row.  With that rule, duplicate expressions are not a burden.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the advice. You are correct, the time format in the example above could be used to sort the results correctly. During my testing this failed once, I was probably using a different time format.